# connecting android to .net web service database

Tags: android, .net, ksoap2

I have a .NET web service that is querying a database.
In my android application i am trying to retrieve a searched(by id) object from the database using the ksoap library.The problem is that am i not getting any errors, but the object is not retrived.I think that the android app is not connecting to the .net webservice...

I have read a lot about this subject and i have not found anything useful.
Is there a special method to retrieve objects?(i have read but not tried something about mapping and serializing).

Does anybody know a good tutorial about this kind of stuff?

I will also post my code if it is necessary.
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You have to implement `KvmSerializable`.You can see [ksoap2-android,CodingTipsAndTricks](https://code.google.com/p/ksoap2-android/wiki/CodingTipsAndTricks) for more details. that is a very good tutorial.

Comment: Thank you.I have made some progress in my application, but now i am getting the following error:

SoapFault - faultcode:'soap:server' faultstring:system.web.services.protocols.soapexception:server was unable to process request-->system.data.sqlclient.sqlexception: an attempt to attach an auto-named database for file "path to my db" failed.a database with the same name exists or specified file cannot be opened or it is located on UNC share"

Thank you!